# How Do I Retrieve Data From a Form after A Button is Clicked using Django

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I have searched for the solution for hours, and all of the solutions that I have found do not work (I'm probably doing something wrong).

I want to be able to retrieve data entered by the user in the "email" and "password" fields of my login page. However, I can't find a working solution. Help?!

```
# the login form

<form>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input id="first-name-input" type="text" placeholder=""/>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input id="last-name-input" type="text" placeholder=""/>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input id="email-input" type="email" placeholder=""/>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input id="password-input" type="password" placeholder=""/>
    <label>Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder=""/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit"/>
<closeform></closeform></form>
```

Comment: You'll need to show us the view code which processes this form...

Comment: Also, it's a bit strange that your form tag does not have a `method` attribute.  Most forms have `method="post"`.

Comment: Doesn't your form need an `action="path/to/processing/file"` attribute to be able to process the form within said file?

Answer (score 0):

First, as [John Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon) has already mentioned in the comments your form probably needs to have a `method="post"`.

Second, if that method is `post`, which it should be if it's a login form, then you have to include the `{% csrf_token %}`.

Finally, when an HTML form is sent it uses the `name` attribute of the inputs to send the information in key-value pairs, where the key is the `name` and the value is the actual input.  Otherwise there will be nothing to send.

You have `id`'s for your inputs, which is fine.  I changed the `id` attribute to `name` attibutes, but there's no reason you can't have both if you want.

```html
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input name="first-name-input" type="text" placeholder=""/>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input name="last-name-input" type="text" placeholder=""/>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email-input" type="email" placeholder=""/>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input name="password-input" type="password" placeholder=""/>
    <label>Confirm Password</label>
    <input name=""password-confirm-input" type="password" placeholder=""/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Also, check out [django-allauth!](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is a third-party authentication for django, which is easy to install and use, and does a lot of the authentication work for you.  No need to reinvent the wheel for common tasks like this, unless your goal is to write it as a learning tool.